# Using variables inside strings

Tags: c#, string, string-formatting

In PHP I can do the following:

```
$name = 'John';
$var = "Hello {$name}";    // => Hello John
```

Is there a similar language construct in C#?

I know there is `String.Format();` but I want to know if it can be done without calling a function/method on the string.

Answer (score 311, accepted):

In C# 6 you can use [string interpolation](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Languages-features-in-C%23-6-and-VB-14):

```
string name = "John";
string result = $"Hello {name}";
```

The syntax highlighting for this in Visual Studio makes it highly readable and all of the tokens are checked.

Comment: Good solution. But why does it make sense, that all tokens are checked?

Answer (score 97):

This functionality is not built-in to C# 5 or below.
**Update: C# 6 now supports string interpolation, see newer answers.**

The recommended way to do this would be with `String.Format`:

```
string name = "Scott";
string output = String.Format("Hello {0}", name);
```

However, I wrote a small open-source library called [**SmartFormat**](http://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat/) that extends `String.Format` so that it can use named placeholders (via reflection).  So, you could do:

```
string name = "Scott";
string output = Smart.Format("Hello {name}", new{name}); // Results in "Hello Scott".
```

Hope you like it!

Comment: What kind of performance penalty is there for using your reflection implementation vs the standard string.Format?

Comment: I see you already have a [performance page](https://github.com/scottrippey/SmartFormat.NET/wiki/Performance) on the wiki. It looks quite promising. Nice work!

Comment: Yes, I believe the performance page probably addresses your question, but I haven't run any comparisons between "Hello {0}" vs "Hello {name}".  Obviously the reflection will take longer.  However, using the caching feature improves parsing performance, and could minimize the difference.  Either way, things are FAST!

Comment: This is no longer true. C#6 added this as a feature

Answer (score 31):

Use the following methods

1: Method one

```
var count = 123;
var message = $"Rows count is: {count}";
```

2: Method two

```
var count = 123;
var message = "Rows count is:" + count;
```

3: Method three

```
var count = 123;
var message = string.Format("Rows count is:{0}", count);
```

4: Method four

```
var count = 123;
var message = @"Rows
                count
                is:" + count;
```

5: Method five

```
var count = 123;
var message = $@"Rows 
                 count 
                 is:{count}";
```

Comment: It would be nice to add a comment as to why you would choose using each of these methods.

Comment: How do you do: `var count = 123; var text = "Rows count is: {count}"; var message = $text;`?

Comment: obviously methods 4 and 5 returns completly different string than 1 to 3 (to count as the same first method should be `$"Rows\n                count\n                is: {count}";`)

Answer (score 6):

Up to C#5 (-VS2013) you have to call a function/method for it. Either a "normal" function such as `String.Format` or an overload of the + operator.

```
string str = "Hello " + name; // This calls an overload of operator +.
```

In C#6 (VS2015) string interpolation has been introduced (as described by other answers).

Answer (score -1):

I saw this question and similar questions and I preferred to use a built-in method for the problem of using a dictionary of values to fill-in placeholders in a template string. Here's my solution, which is built on the StringFormatter class from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36778184/193974):

```
    public static void ThrowErrorCodeWithPredefinedMessage(Enums.ErrorCode errorCode, Dictionary<string, object> values)
    {
        var str = new StringFormatter(MSG.UserErrorMessages[errorCode]) { Parameters = values};
        var applicationException = new ApplicationException($"{errorCode}", new ApplicationException($"{str.ToString().Replace("@","")}"));
        throw applicationException;
    }
```

where the message exists in a Dictionary that is not in the caller, but the caller only has access to Enums.ErrorCode, and can build an argument array and send it to the above method as argument.

assuming we have the value of MSG.UserErrorMessages[errorCode] is originally

```
"The following entry exists in the dump but is not found in @FileName: @entryDumpValue"
```

The result of this call

```
 var messageDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object> {
                    { "FileName", sampleEntity.sourceFile.FileName}, {"entryDumpValue", entryDumpValue }
                };
                ThrowErrorCodeWithPredefinedMessage(Enums.ErrorCode.MissingRefFileEntry, messageDictionary);
```

is

```
The following entry exists in the dump but is not found in cellIdRules.ref: CellBand = L09
```

The only restriction to this approach is to avoid using '@' in the contents of any of the passed values.

Comment: There is no built-in StringFormatter class in .Net, where did you find it?

Comment: Hi @Vitaly you're right I added the source in my answer. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score -3):

you can define a variable as string like this in C#

`var varName= data.Values["some var"] as string;`