# c# How to insert a variable into a string?

Tags: c#, string

I would like to know the different ways of inserting a variable into a string, in C#.

I am currently trying to insert values into a json string that I am building:

```
 Random rnd = new Random();
  int ID = rnd.Next(1, 999);
  string body = @"{""currency"":""country"",""gold"":1,""detail"":""detailid-979095986"",""tId"":""help here""}";
```

How could I add the "ID" to the string body?

Comment: Don't write JSON by hand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert variable values in the middle of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13033581/insert-variable-values-in-the-middle-of-a-string)

Answer (score 5):

In a typical string inserting scenario, I'd do one of these:

```
string body = string.Format("My ID is {0}", ID);
string body = "My ID is " + ID;
```

However, your string is apparently JSON serialized data. I'd expect that I'd want to parse that into a class in order to work with it.

```
var myObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(someString);
myObj.TID = ID;
// maybe do other things with it, then if I need JSON again...
string body = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myObj);
```

One reason to take this approach is to make sure that any data I put in still makes the JSON valid. For example, if my ID were, instead of an `int`, a `string` with characters that needed escaping, directly inserting `"\"\n\""` would not be the right thing to do.

Comment: +1 for the right answer of serializing a data object to JSON.

Answer (score 5):

[String interpolation is the easiest way these days:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

```
int myIntValue = 123;
string myStringValue = "one two three";
string interpolatedString = $"my int is: {myIntValue}. My string is: {myStringValue}.";
```

Output would be "*my int is: 123. My string is: one two three.*".

You can experiment with this sample yourself, [over here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/nhEqpd).

> The $ special character identifies a string literal as an interpolated
>   string. An interpolated string is a string literal that might contain
>   interpolation expressions. When an interpolated string is resolved to
>   a result string, items with interpolation expressions are replaced by
>   the string representations of the expression results. **This feature is available starting with C# 6.**

Answer (score 2):

You could try this:

```
string body = @"{""currency"":""country"",""gold"":1,""detail"":""detailid-979095986"",""tId"":""" + ID + @"""}";
```

You can also use [`string.Concat`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.concat.aspx):

```
string body = string.Concat(@"{""currency"":""country"",""gold"":1,""detail"":""detailid-979095986"",""tId"":""", ID, @"""}");
```

Comment: I love YOU
i hope i could rep you but i need 15 to do so

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways to inject values into strings, however it's easy to lose sight of encodings, and cause major breakage.

If you just want to inject a value into another string, you can use:

- string concatenation
- string building
- string formatting

### Concatenation:

The simplest and most common way to build strings is by simply [concatenating them together](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228504.aspx) with the `+` operator:

```
var foo = 5;
var bar = "example-" + foo;
```

Concatenation can be difficult to read which makes it easy to introduce bugs, but for most simple tasks is the right tool for the job.

In this case, it's a poor choice:

```
string body = @"{""currency"":""country"",""gold"":1,""detail"":""detailid-979095986"",""tId"":""" + ID.ToString() + @"""}";
```

### String Building

The [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class is useful for building large strings particularly when built iteratively.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    sb.Append(i.ToString());
    sb.Append(" ");
}
var output = sb.ToString();
```

It can still be difficult to read and hard to debug, but for cases where you're joining lots of strings together, it's super efficient

In this case, it's a poor choice:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"{""currency"":""country"",""gold"":1,""detail"":""detailid-979095986"",""tId"":""");
sb.Append(ID.ToString());
sb.Append(@"""}");
string body = sb.ToString();
```

### String formatting

The [`string.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx) method makes templating data into a string super easy and efficient. If you plan on reusing the same string over and over, using a format string makes it much easier to read and debug code, particularly when there are lots of replacements:

```
var foo = 5;
var bar = string.Format("example-{0}", foo);
```

Format strings can also automatically apply culturally accurate formatting to particular data types, so that a `DateTime` is appropriately displayed, or so that a number has the appropriate number of trailing zeros.

In this case, it's a poor choice:

```
string string.Format(@"{""currency"":""country"",""gold"":1,""detail"":""detailid-979095986"",""tId"":""{0}""}", ID);
```

### The right choice

You're not dumping data into any old string. That's JSON encoded data. If you just concatenate/build/format in any old value, you can break your string. For example, if the `ID` variable contained a `"` character, you'd break the entire JSON dataset.

Additionally, the length of the string and necessary quotes make it super difficult to read, which makes it difficult to maintain. Good luck when you get around to needing to add another formatted value, it's going to be a pain to change any existing value or add in new dynamic ones.

Instead of writing a JSON literal, write an object and encode it to JSON:

```
var bodyData =
    new
        {
            currency = "country",
            gold = 1,
            detail = "detailid-979095986",
            tId = ID //here's where you set the ID
        };
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var body = jss.Serialize(bodyData);
```

This code is much easier to modify when the data changes, and will actually encode your data correctly. You don't need to worry about all those annoying double quote characters any more either.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the

```
String.Format(@"{""currency"":""country"",""gold"":1,""detail"":""detailid-979095986"",""tId"":""{0}""}", ID)
```

Since this is `params object[]`, you can use as many `{n}` as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using on string, you could concatenate strings together using +, which would allow you to insert text between the generated strings.

```
string body = @"***" + ID + @"***";
```