# Variable in the dynamic string in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have a module to send message with the SMS. I can put the variable in the string if the message is a static, but the user request the message can be changed whatever their want.

I created this variable

1. CompanyName
2. CustomerName
3. BillNumber
4. Payment

Example :

> From **{Company}**. Hi Mr/Mrs **{CustomerName}**, your bill number is
>   **{BillNumber}** with a total payment of **{Payment}**. We want to inform you
>   the items has been completed and ready for collection.

My current code is work for static message,

```
string messageSms = "From " +Company+ ". Hi Mr/Mrs "+{CustomerName}+", your bill number is "+{BillNumber}+" with a total payment of "+{Payment}+". We want to inform you the items has been completed and ready for collection.";
```

But how can be done with dynamic message? How can I detect the variable in the string and set the data on the variable?

I also following with this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227413/c-sharp-variables-in-strings) but not help so much.

Comment: can you give an example of a desired input/output?

Comment: can you clearify more about the case that you want to handle ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming I'm understanding, i think the [`String.Inject`](http://mo.notono.us/2008/07/c-stringinject-format-strings-by-key.html) class could be helpful. Picture a named `String.Format`:

```
"Hello, {company}!".Inject(new { company = "StackOverflow" });
// "Hello, StackOverflow!"
```

The other benefit is you can have a hard-coded model and reference direct properties of it. e.g.

```
class Contact
{
    string FirstName;
    string LastName;
}

String greeting = "Mr. {FirstName} {LastName}, Welcome to the site ...";
String result = greeting.Inject(new Contact
{
    FirstName = "Brad",
    LastName = "Christie"
});
```

Comment: May I know what framework to allow use String.Inject property? I'm use version 3.5 where the String.Inject property is not avaible

Comment: @Chuki2: You need to include the [class](http://austegard.googlepages.com/StringInjectExtension.cs) listed on that page in your project, then add it as a `using` statement.

Comment: @BradChristie, sorry, I did not realize about that. Let me try

Comment: @BradChristie, Simple and awesome.. Thanks for help!

Comment: @AzriZakaria this method is a custom class and it is not part of C# String class methods.

Answer (score 8):

```
var newString = messageSms.Replace("{Company}", CompanyName)
                          .Replace("{CustomerName}", CustomerName) // ...etc
```

Should do it.

Answer (score 5):

You could also use [interpolated strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160.aspx) using C# 6.0

```cs
var messageSms = $"From {companyName}. Hi {customerName}, your bill number is {billNumber} with a total payment of {payment}.";
```

Answer (score 4):

I would approach with the following :

```
string Company;
string CustomerName;
string BillNumber;
string Payment;

string messageSms = $@"
From {Company}. Hi Mr/Mrs {CustomerName}, your bill number is {BillNumber} 
with a total payment of {Payment}. We want to inform you the items has been 
completed and ready for collection.
";
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `String.Format` Method, for example:

```
string messageSms = String.Format("From {0}. Hi ..{1}, Your..{2} with..{3}. We..", 
                                  CompanyName, CustomerName, BillNumber, Payment);
```

Comment: This doesn't match the OPs' "named parameter" requirement.

Comment: Yes that true, as programmer easy to understand it but not for user. That's why i need use named parameter. By the way thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the easiest way to achieve this (you did not clarify your question) is to use `string.Format()`.
Just use it like this:

```
string company = ...;
string name= ...;
string billNr= ...;
string payment= ...;
string output = string.Format("From {0}. Hi Mr/Mrs {1}, your bill number is {2} with a total payment of {3}. We want to inform you the items has been completed and ready for collection.", company, name, billNr, payment);
```

Comment: For user,with this way is not friendly and can make confuse. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `StringBuilder` instead?

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("From {Company}.Hi Mr/Mrs {CustomerName}, your bill number is {BillNumber} with a total payment of {Payment}. We want to inform you the items has been completed and ready for collection.");
stringBuilder.Replace("{Company}",CompanyName);
stringBuilder.Replace("{CustomerName}",CustomerName);
stringBuilder.Replace("{BillNumber}",BillNumber);
stringBuilder.Replace("{Payment}",Payment);
string messageSms = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a reusable solution you could start by declaring an object that contains the replacement values as properties. In this case I simply declare an anonymous object but a normal class would work just as well:

```
var data = new {
  Company = "Stack Overflow",
  CustomerName = "Martin Liversage",
  BillNumber = 123456,
  Payment = 1234.567M.ToString("N2")
};
```

Notic how I "cheat" and assign a string to `Payment`. Number and date/time formatting is always a complex issue and I have decided to do the formatting up-front when I declare the data object. You could instead build some more or less elaborate formatting rules into the formatting engine.

Having a data object with properties I can build a dictionary of name/value pairs:

```
var dictionary = data
  .GetType()
  .GetProperties()
  .ToDictionary(
    propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name,
    propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(data, null)
  );
```

Assuming that `format` contains the formatting template it is simply a matter of looping over the elements in the dictionary to create the replacement string:

```
var buffer = new StringBuilder(format);
foreach (var name in dictionary.Keys) {
  var value = dictionary[name].ToString();
  buffer.Replace("{" + name + "}", value);
}
var message = buffer.ToString();
```