# Use variable in XPath

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

This is working, but I want to use the text **Group 1** as a variable.

Code trials:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)= 'Group 1'])[1]/ancestor::app-organization//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Create a new board...']/following::input[1]")]
public IWebElement BoardNameInputField { get; set; }
```

I tried this but with no success:

```
string boardName = "Group 1";

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='${boardName}'])[1]/ancestor::app-organization//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Create a new board...']")]
public IWebElement CreateNewBoard { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using variables inside strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227413/using-variables-inside-strings)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are setting the variable *boardName* to **Group 1** you need to change:

```
How.XPath, Using = "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='${boardName}'])[1]/ancestor::app-organization//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Create a new board...']")]
```

as:

```
How.XPath, Using = "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='" + boardName + "'])[1]/ancestor::app-organization//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Create a new board...']")]
```

Effectively we changed:

```
normalize-space(.)='${boardName}'
```

to:

```
normalize-space(.)='" + boardName + "'
```

Comment: what is better to use String.Format or string concatenation? :)

Answer (score 5):

In string interpolation the `$` should be before the string, not the variable

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = $"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='{boardName}'])[1]/ancestor::app-organization//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Create a new board...']")]
```

In addition, `boardName` need to be static to be used outside method scope

```
static string boardName = "Group 1";
```

Comment: This is the answer to OP's question! (However: string interpolation is turned into `string.Format()` at compile-time hence my answer... :) )

Comment: @MosheSlavin True, but it looks like the OP tried to do it, he used `'${boardName}'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `String.Format` with [inserting-a-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#inserting-a-string):

```
string boardName = "Group 1";

[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = String.Format("(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='{0}'])[1]/ancestor::app-organization//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Create a new board...'])", boardName)]
public IWebElement CreateNewBoard { get; set; }
```

Hope this helps you!