# How to use string.format with array of arguments names as argument?

Tags: c#, string.format

I want to create string from variables based on format of another string.
It passes only string names, not references. Ref is not working. What can i do?

```cs
var format = "city, post_code, street, building_number,name"
var city = model["City"];
var post_code = model["Post_Code"];
var street = model["Street"];
var building_number = model["Building_Number"];
var name = model["Name"];
var arguments = format.Split(",");
var s = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", new object[] {  arguments[0],  arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4] });
```

Comment: can you also include what are your expected value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use strings as variable names. C# is not PHP.

What you actually want is string interpolation:

```
var s = $"{city}, {post_code}, {street}, {building_number}, {name}";
```

Now if you want this format string to be variable, see:

- [Is there a "String.Format" that can accept named input parameters instead of index placeholders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759694/is-there-a-string-format-that-can-accept-named-input-parameters-instead-of-ind)
- [Using variables inside strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227413/using-variables-inside-strings)
- [What's a good way of doing string templating in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733378/whats-a-good-way-of-doing-string-templating-in-net)

Comment: I know, but i need to format this "s" string as in format. 
Something like this? I have to order it like in format string.
var s = $"format";

Comment: Yeah so see the linked questions.

Comment: I fell so stupid right now.
var format = "{var1},{var2}";
var finalString = $"{format}";

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the expected result/functionality here.

Is format a static Information or can it vary? I interpreted the question as the later is inteded. A (quite basic) solution could be:

```
    public void foo(DataRow model, String format = "city,post_code,street,building_number,name")
    {
        var arguments = format.Split(',');

        var val1 = model[arguments[0]];
        var val2 = model[arguments[1]];
        var val3 = model[arguments[2]];
        var val4 = model[arguments[3]];
        var val5 = model[arguments[4]];

        var s = $"{val1} {val2} {val3} {val4} {val5}";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, I cant give you upvote but it works quite good :)

Answer (score -1):

You are not using the `String.Format` correctly. Modify your code like this

```
var s = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4}", arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3], arguments[4]);
```

Comment: No. `arguments[0]` is "city", but the OP wants the _value of the variable named `city`_ to be printed there. Also, both you and the OP are using the `String.Format(string, params object[] args)` overload, both syntaxes call the same method. See also http://www.ideone.com/mmf3PQ.