# String format template as parameter

Tags: c#, string, parameters, format

I'm beginer in C#. Now I have next task: In method I get template and arguments and I have to return formated string.

For example:

```
template = "Hello, {name}!"

name = "Bob"
```

So result must be a string -> Hello, Bob!

```
public static string GetHelloGreeting(string template, string name)
{
    return string.Format(template, name);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using variables inside strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227413/using-variables-inside-strings)

Comment: And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36759694/, The chain of dupe is too long on that one

Comment: @DragandDrop: string interplation is not what OP is asking for. You can just use it directly, not if you get a format string like in `GetHelloGreeting`. `String.Format` can do that, but only with indexes not with names. While some answers(in your links) suggest third party libraries which support it, it will not help OP because he said that he's a beginner and got a task(probably from the teacher).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.Format` expects an index in the braces. You want to pass the name in it, so you can replace it with the actual name value.
I'd suggest to use `String.Replace`:

```
public static string GetHelloGreeting(string template, string name)
{
    return template.Replace("{name}", name);
}
```

You could provide a method which is more reusable. For example:

```
public static string ReplaceAll(string template, params (string key, string value)[] replacements)
{
    foreach (var kv in replacements)
    {
        template = template.Replace("{"+ kv.key + "}", kv.value);
    }

    return template;
}
```

Your example:

```
string res = ReplaceAll("Hello, {name}!", ("name", "Bob"));
```

but also possible with multiple parameters:

```
string res = ReplaceAll("Hello, {name}! Now it's {time}", ("name", "Bob"), ("time", DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm")));
```

Comment: Yes, it helped me. I think the Replace method is the best way to solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: In the end I use 
`Replace("{" + nameof(name) + "}", name)`

Answer (score 0):

when specifying a format you use an index for the parameters that will follow. It is called a [composite format string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting):

```
string template = "Hello, {0}!"
```

this makes it independent of variable names. But the true reason is that the overload of the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0#system-string-format(system-string-system-object())) method that you are using takes a params array as parameter as you can see in the method signature:

```
public static string Format (string format, params object?[] args);
```

so the index that is found in the template will be applied to extract the objects on the appropriate places from the array of objects that you pass into the method

Comment: I have different test methods that my method must conform to. In them, the `template` looks exactly as I have shown. I thought replace name of parameter to index but in next method I have the same task but with 2 params with different position.

Answer (score 0):

The value of your `template` parameter will have to change somehow. If you want to use string interpolation, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227413/using-variables-inside-strings) shows that. So
`template = $"Hello, {name}";` in which case you wouldn't need to use `String.Format` at all. Just make sure you define `name` before you define `template`.

Or you could use `String.Format(template, name);` like you have but you would need `template = "Hello, {0}!";`
The `0` is the index of the variable that will go in that position. For more info see [`String.Format`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use  `string.Format()`, the `template` must be correct. Add the character `$` at the beginning of the `template`:

try this:

```
  string name = "Bob";
  string template = $"Hello, {name}!";

  Console.WriteLine(GetHelloGreeting(template, name)); // Hello, Bob!
     
  public static string GetHelloGreeting(string template, string name)
  {
       return string.Format(template, name);
  }
```

reult:

> Hello, Bob!

Comment: doesn't this makes the entire `GetHelloGreeting` method obsolete ?=!

Comment: @MongZhu I wanted to answer the way the question was asked, otherwise it will be answered:  `Console.WriteLine("Hello, {0}!",name)`

Comment: what I wanted to say is that the complete string is already in `template` before you pass it into the method. the string.format call does not do anything extra